# Ошибка NoSuchBeanDefinitionException //Spring

Tags: java, spring

Только начал изучать Spring, поэтому очень трудно увидеть ошибку.
Имеется класс конфигурации:

```
@Configuration
public class Context {
@Bean
public mainClass vvvclass() {

    return new mainClass();
}
}
```

Класс с Autowired:

```
public class mainClass implements miniInterface {

@Autowired
private Argument arg;

@Autowired
private Work work;

@Override
public void MainMethod()throws IOException {
 work.sheetsInsert(arg.Arguments(), null, arg.retArg());
}
```

}

И Main:

```
public class Start {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    ApplicationContext ctx = new 
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Context.class);
    mainClass cclass = ctx.getBean(mainClass.class);
    cclass.MainMethod();

}
}
```

Ошибка:

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling 
refresh attempt: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error 
creating bean with name 'vvvclass': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through 
field 'arg'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No 
qualifying bean of type 'JAVA.Concert.Argument' available: expected at least 
1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
Exception in thread "main" 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error 
creating bean with name 'vvvclass': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through 
field 'arg'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No 
qualifying bean of type 'JAVA.Concert.Argument' available: expected at least 
1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 'JAVA.Concert.Argument' available: expected at 
least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Классы Work и Argument помечены аннотацией Component. Укажите пожалуйста на проблему)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Spring не видит классы `Work` и `Argument` как бины. В вашей конфигурации вы создаёте только бин `mainClass`, в классе `Context`, а бины `Work` и `Argument` не создаёте. Spring не пытается создать их, потому что вы не просите его сканировать пакеты на предмет классов, помеченных аннотацией `@Component`. Вам нужно либо создавать бины `Work` и `Argument` так же, как бин `mainClass`, либо пометить `Context` аннотацией `@ComponentScan` с указанием пакетов, в которых нужно искать классы, помеченные аннотацией `@Component`.

Comment: Добавил @ComponentScan и теперь такая ошибка: NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'JAVA.Concert.Argument' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: argument,work

Comment: У вас случайно `Argument` не унаследован от `Work` (или наоборот)? Добавьте в вопрос код этих классов, без них проблему сложно диагностировать точно.

Comment: Argument и Work никак не связаны, до этого конфигурацию производил через xml файл и все работало.

Comment: Тогда, возможно, у вас есть другие наследники `Argument` в пакете, который вы сканируете. Или ещё один Java-конфиг, создающий бин `Argument` явно. Приведите ваш код, чтобы попытка помочь вам не превращалась в гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: Все, спасибо большое за помощь, при попытке выложить код обнаружил что Work действительно наследуется от Argument ))